# How to show that a map is finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V = Z\left(X^3 - Y^2\right)\in \mathbb{k}^2$. How to show that $f \colon t \in \mathbb{C} \mapsto \left(t^2, t^3\right) \in V$ is a finite map?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What definition are you using?

Comment: A morphism is finite if and only if it is proper and quasi-finite.

Comment: Well, quasi-finiteness is clear, right? So you just need to check that the map is proper.

Comment: Can we say that $f$ is a finite morphism and how to check that proper condition?

Comment: You could use the valuative criterion for properness, but I think it would be much easier to just use the standard definition of finite morphism in terms of finite algebras.

Comment: On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_morphism there is an explanation, but we didn't introduce schemes. So how to show it without schemes?

Comment: @Zhen's suggestion is excellent but I'll let him write it up himself if he so wishes. I have written an answer based on a completely different idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's do it the sly way:
Consider the morphism $$F:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^2: (t:u)\mapsto (x:y:z)=(t^2u:t^3:u^3)$$ It is proper because its source is the complete variety $\mathbb P^1$.
But then all its restrictions coming from open subsets downstairs are proper too and in particular taking as the open subset downstairs  $V=\mathbb A^2=\{z\neq0\}\subset \mathbb P^2$ we deduce that $$f=F|F^{-1}(V):F^{-1}(V)=\mathbb A^1 \to V=\mathbb A^2$$ is proper.

Comment: Incredible! How do you see those relations?

Comment: Dear aGer, I see them because, like many algebraic geometers, I'm used to  working  essentially in projective space. You see, the basic definitions, both in classical algebraic geometry and scheme theory, are given first  in affine space because there  the algebra is nice and easy. However one soon becomes aware of the deficiencies of affine space: for example two distinct lines in an affine plane can meet in two points or one (if they are parallel). This doesn't happen in a projectiveplane where they always meet in exactly one point.

Comment: (follow-up of previous comment) Much more generally Bézout's theorem is a wonderful example of a theorem valid in projective space  and false in affine space.  It is quite normal and healthy to begin with affine varieties. But then one must move on to projective space where many more interesting  theorems can be proved. This is similar to the process of first learning differential calculus in open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$  and then moving on to differential manifolds.